# How to prevent text from overflowing the textbox due to large font-size?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that uses a custom font for textbox values that I designed. When I set the font to size 72, it doesnt shows in report because of the huge space that adds to the top of the font. Can someone help me fix this issue so I can get rid of the extra space at the top to enable display the font letters correctly?

Here is my custom font and the space above the two letters used in the screenshot is causing the problem. I designed this font.

[image: screenshot]

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a carriage return in the text value causing it to wrap to another line? If that space is built into the font design there is not much you can do about it in the report.

Comment: It turns out, the space was in the font. I fixed the font since I designed it :) Thank you for responding, Nathan.

Comment: Are you sure creating your own font for something like this is the best approach? Doesn't this require you to install the font for any client running this code?

Comment: This is actually a custom solution which we are developing in-house and we have full control over the server that will run these reports :)